# How do I calculate shipping in Simplecart based on total quantity?

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, simplecart

My client requires shipping rates based on quantity of items in the order.

1-10 books - $4
11-24 - $5.50
25-49 - $7
50-99- $8.50
100-199 - $11
200-299 - $16
300-399 - $23
400-499 - $30

I've been trying to tweak the JavaScript a week now. Anybody know Simplecart well enough to send me in the right direction?

Comment: just added this to core at ln 861 and commented out original fn ` me.shipping = function(){
  var q = parseInt(me.quantity,10);
  if(q <= 10){
   return 4;
  }
  if((q >= 11) && (q <= 24)){
   return 5.5;
  }
  if((q >= 25) && (q <= 49)){
   return 7;
  }
  if((q >= 50) && (q <= 99)){
   return 8.5;
  }
  if((q >= 100) && (q <= 199)){
   return 11;
  }
  if((q >= 200) && (q <= 299)){
   return 16;
  }
  if((q >= 300) && (q <= 399)){
   return 23;
  }
  if((q >= 400) && (q <= 499)){
   return 30;
  }
 }
`

Comment: any suggestions on using prototype to overwrite existing method in Cart class to do this less messy?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to change the core files.

See http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/shipping

```
simpleCart.shipping(function(){
    if( simpleCart.quantity() <= 10 ){
         return 4;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 25 ){
         return 5.5;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 50 ){
         return 7.5;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 100 ){
         return 8.5;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 200 ){
         return 11;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 300 ){
         return 16;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 400 ){
         return 23;
    }
    else if( simpleCart.quantity() < 500 ){
         return 30;
    }
    else {
         return 30; // amount for > 500
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
simpleCart({
  shippingCustom: function () { 
    if (simpleCart.quantity() > 50) {
      return 0;
    } else if (simpleCart.quantity() > 20) {
      return 10;
    } else {
      return 20;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.